# mxgraph in Typescript Cannot set property 'mxImageBasePath' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, mxgraph

I tried this method to use mxgraph library inside Angular 8 application. 
I tried to import mxgraph like this.

```
declare var require: any;
const mx = require("mxgraph")({
  mxImageBasePath: "assets/images",
  mxBasePath: "assets"
});
```

But I got this error and couldn't find the way to fix this.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Dennis, have you found a solution? Having the same issue here...

Comment: Hi @Marco I made my own packages for this and published in npmjs. You can find them. 
[ts-mxgraph](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mxgraph)
[ts-mxgraph-factory](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mxgraph-factory)
[ts-mxgraph-typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mxgraph-typings)